# Illegal mix of collations (latin5_turkish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

How can i solve

```
"Illegal mix of collations (latin5_turkish_ci,IMPLICIT) 
and (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) 
for operation '='" problem?
```

My query: `select * from up where name='camış'`

connection options:

```
SET NAMES 'latin5'
SET character_set_connection = 'latin5'
SET collation_connection = latin5_turkish_ci
```

--
I changed the collate as latin5_turkish_ci but doesn't work.
Between, after a few minutes (lots of queries), the problem disappears on its own.

Comment: what's the meaning of camış?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rather bad idea but should work:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM up 
 WHERE CONVERT(name USING latin5) COLLATE latin5_turkish_ci = 'camış'
```

Good idea is to convert all your column to desired character set (and this should be UTF-8).

[+] By converting I mean not changing default collation of table/column, but to convert all data in it. So I would create new column with target character set, populate it with `UPDATE table SET new_column = CONVERT(old_column USING characterset)`, drop old column and rename new one.

Comment: Thank you. I get this. But i already changed the character set for the table with alter table. Is there another mysql statement for that?